# concatena two columns Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have two date columns in my table (db is oracle).Now,I need to concatenate their time values such that I get this:
Column 1
21 september 2015 12:00:00
Column 2:
21 september 2015 2:00:00
I need to represent it like this 
12:00:00PM-2:00:00PM

I know I can do something like this:

```
Select (to_char(date)) || '-' || 'PM' || (to_char(date)) || 'PM'
```

Syntax maybe incorrect but I am only concerned with the logic for now.Actually,I don't want to hardcode this PM, because some of my times are AM.

Is there a way to do this in oracle 12c?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  to_char(sysdate,'HH:MI:SS PM') || ' - ' || to_char(sysdate + 120/1400,'HH:MI:SS PM')
from
  dual
```

**`09:48:52 AM - 11:52:18 AM`**